# Python neo4j-rest-client takes too long within a flask view

Tags: python, neo4j, flask

I am developing a web application using flask and neo4j. I use noe4j-rest-client for the python side. When I query neo4j using python shell, it takes 78ms. But when I make request within a flask view it takes 0.8seconds. I have profiled and I see that neo4j-rest-client/request.py is the responsible, because it takes 0.5 seconds. What do you think ?

Comment: Perhaps you can add more details on what you want to do? Datamodel, use-case, query, code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is taking too much time, you might want to implement your own REST client that uses a faster parser, or speed up neo4j-rest-client and submit a patch?